# Unable to run a command from php to linux

Tags: php, html, linux

I was trying to run a command from PHP to my Linux server but I'm having some trouble with one command:
This is the script:

```
<?php
  $output=null;
  $retval=null;
  exec('speedtest -L -f, --format=json 2>&1', $output, $retval);
  echo "Returned with status $retval and output:\n";
  print_r($output);
?>
```

The output is:

```
Returned with status 134 and output: 
       Array ( [0] => terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' 
               [1] => what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid 
               [2] => Aborted (core dumped))
```

The user that runs the script is: www-data
if I try to run it directly on the terminal it works.

```
command from terminal: sudo -u www-data speedtest -L
output: {"type":"serverList","timestamp":"2021-02-23T09:20:51Z","servers":[{"id":4302,"name":"Vodafone IT","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"speedtest.vodafone.it","port":8080},{"id":7839,"name":"Fastweb SpA","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"spd-pub-mi-01-01.fastwebnet.it","port":8080},{"id":11427,"name":"EOLO","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"test.eolo.it","port":8080},{"id":1434,"name":"CWNET","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"speedtest.cheapnet.it","port":8080},{"id":3667,"name":"TIM SpA","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"speedtestmi1.telecomitalia.it","port":8080},{"id":8211,"name":"CDLAN S.R.L.","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"speedtest.cdlan.it","port":8080},{"id":11675,"name":"Italiaonline Supernap","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"speedtest-supernap.italiaonline.it","port":8080},{"id":20551,"name":"Optima Italia","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"mi-speedtest.optimaitalia.com","port":8080},{"id":26415,"name":"P-Lab","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"speed.speedymilan.net","port":8080},{"id":19177,"name":"Seeweb","location":"Milan","country":"Italy","host":"ookla-mil.seeweb.it","port":8080}]}
```

If I run another command it works perfectly:

```
<?php
  $output=null;
  $retval=null;
  exec('whoami', $output, $retval);
  sleep(1);
  echo "Returned with status $retval and output:\n";
  print_r($output);
?>
```

The output is:

```
Returned with status 0 and output: Array ( [0] => www-data )
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: www-data has no shell until you set one. Don't do that. Create an extra user for that and use su.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks for the answer. Could u explain to me how to set it correctly? I was trying to do it but I'm stuck.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong when ` sudo -u www-data speedtest -L` is working properly. What happens if you try `exec('sudo -u www-data speedtest -L -f, --format=json 2>&1', $output, $retval);`? Maybe it is an apache module thing?

Comment: @MarkusZeller it says: "Returned with status 1 and output: www-data is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported. ".

Comment: @MarkusZeller it says: "Returned with status 1 and output:"

Comment: I think some parameter is wrong. I tried this working well `exec('sudo su -l www-data -s /bin/bash -c "ps -aux"', $output);`. Maybe reduce arguments for testing. `exec('sudo su -l www-data -s /bin/bash -c "speedtest -L"', $output);`

Comment: @MarkusZeller with the last one it says: "Returned with status 1 and output: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper"

Comment: What does happen on simple `exec('speedtest -L', $output);` as I suppose it may be "wrong" arguments? Maybe the speedtest does require some terminal (TTY) to run?

Comment: It says: "Returned with status 134 and output:"

Comment: Another approach: `$output = shell_exec('speedtest -L');` When you need an array, you can explode with PHP_EOL. On the other hand: JSON is also a string.

Comment: Did you try my last suggestion with `shell_exec()`?

Comment: I try it but it didn't work, then tried another way that works for now. (Look at the UPDATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to make it work but probably isn't the best one:

```
<?php
// attributes
        private $output;
        private $retval;
        private $command;

        // methods
        function get_serverUpdates($user, $password) {
            $command = 'echo '.$password.' | su -l '.$user.'-s /bin/bash -c "speedtest -L -f, --format=json" 2>&1';
            $resl = exec($command, $output, $retval);
            return json_decode(substr($resl, 10));
        }
?>
```

It does return the correct information.

I think the problem was that as @MarkusZeller said that www-data doesn't have the permission to run all the programs installed.